# dependency injection without singleton in ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ecmascript-6

Just converted my app to ember-cli, but I don't know how to use `Ember.Application.register` any more because `register` doesn't seem to be available when Application is started with `extend` rather than `create`.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import App from 'myapp/app';

var AdminMyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});

// THROWS ERROR HERE BECAUSE register isn't, uh...registered?
App.register('controller:adminMyController', AdminMyController, { singleton: false });

export default AdminMyController;
```

Previously, because App was a global, I could register this right in the same class.

Am I going to have to move all the register calls to an initializer so I can get access to the app instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive an initializer would do this for you.  You'll need to create an `initializers` folder in your app directory (same level as controllers, templates, etc).  This file should go there.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var AdminMyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    ...
});

export default {
    name: 'adminMyController',
    initialize: function (container, application) {
        container.register('controller:adminMyController', AdminMyController, {singleton: false});
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, this was my solution in the end. It'd be nicer to register with the container IN the file in question, but I'm still not sure how to do that without GLOBALS.